# is the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ Closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was trying to find an open cover for the set $S = \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ that has no finite subcover in order to show that S is not compact and I was wondering if S is a closed set in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Sorry if this is question is too easy, I'm new to topology and I couldn't find this specific question in any of the answered questions.

Comment: Does it contains it is limit points?

Comment: I don't think it contains any of it's limit points. Reason being, not every deleted neighborhood of each real number will contain points in this set. But I'm not sure if my thinking is correcr

Comment: $O=\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$, where $I_k=(\frac{1}k, 2),  k\in \mathbb{N}^+$, $O$ is an open cover on $S$, but you cannot find a finite subcover to cover $S$.

Comment: @sandoh it contains all of its limit points except $0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField could you please elaborate on that for me. I get that $0$ is a limit point of the set. But I don't think the set has any other limit points.

Answer (score 3):

$0$ is a limit point that doesn't belong to the set, so it cannot be closed.

If you really want to use the covering method, just take $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\frac 1n,2)$

You cannot extract a finite subcover, because all these intervals are nested, therefore you need to take the "last one" to cover the set, but this is impossible as there is no last one.